# Peculiar timing result with Blend function

Tags: evaluation, color

First, we load some colorbar data and define `val` for testing

```
Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/gN4wGqxe"]
vals = N@Subdivide[200000];
```

then, definition

```
ClearAll[ParulaCM, ParulaCM2];
ParulaCM = 
  With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ parulaColors}, Blend[colorlist, #] &];
ParulaCM2 = 
  With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ parulaColors}, Blend[colorlist, #] &];
```

You may notice that `ParulaCM` and `ParulaCM2` is exactly the same. I do it on purpose.

Now timing it

```
ParulaCM /@ vals; // AbsoluteTiming
ParulaCM2 /@ vals; // AbsoluteTiming
```

with a fresh start you may probably got this

```
{0.400419, Null}
{1.03218, Null}
```

This is already odd, because `ParulaCM` is the same as `ParulaCM2`. However, `ParulaCM2` is slower

Now you run the previous definition a second time, and time it again. This time you probably got

```
ParulaCM /@ vals; // AbsoluteTiming
ParulaCM2 /@ vals; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.12729, Null}
{1.07233, Null}*)
```

Yeah, they are same again!!

Now even more peculiar, now you run this

[image]

Wow, the `ParulaCM` is fast again.

I am totally lost. What kind of issue is this?

Comment: On [TIO](https://ptpb.pw/brax), whichever being called first is faster. But the slowdown of the other function is indeed weird.

Comment: Have you tried timing with `RepeatedTiming`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Nope, but I think we don't need `RepeatedTiming`..Because, the timing difference is quite clear.

Comment: Hm. In the meantime, I had the opportunity to try it myself. You are right. That's really weird...

Comment: @user202729 I've never seed TIO before.  Does TIO actually use the Wolfram kernel?  Or is it just a 3rd party emulator?

Answer (score 3):

Just speculating here, as this isn't my area.

This is some kind of caching issue.  `Blend` seems to be caching based on the first argument, and then the second time you feed the same expression it's not using the cache and for some reason not able to make another cache.  So in the slower timing, you don't get the benefit of the cache.

If I just use a second list, it doesn't get around the issue,

```
colors2 = parulaColors;

ClearAll[ParulaCM, ParulaCM2];
ParulaCM = 
  With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ parulaColors}, Blend[colorlist, #] &];
ParulaCM2 = 
  With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ colors2}, Blend[colorlist, #] &];

ParulaCM /@ vals; // AbsoluteTiming
ParulaCM2 /@ vals; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.137829, Null} *)
(* {0.461343, Null} *)
```

But if I 'roundtrip' the expression through a string and back, it creates a big enough difference that a new cache can be formed

```
colors2 = parulaColors // ToString // ToExpression;

ClearAll[ParulaCM, ParulaCM2];
ParulaCM = 
  With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ parulaColors}, Blend[colorlist, #] &];
ParulaCM2 = 
  With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ colors2}, Blend[colorlist, #] &];

ParulaCM /@ vals; // AbsoluteTiming
ParulaCM2 /@ vals; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.136792, Null} *)
(* {0.130454, Null} *)
```

This is because the `// ToString // ToExpression` acts on the numeric array to render it not `SameQ` with the original list.  Other round-tripping methods don't work if the result is `SameQ` with the input.

Comment: Hi, Jason B. So you mean that `Blend` will check whether it already met the  exactly same first argument before?  But why add such a check? Is it necessary?

Comment: Caching is done for time saving, but this is definitely a bug.  The caching it's doing is in c code so I don't know a way to disable it.

Comment: actually, I still don't understand. Because `ParulaCM===ParulaCM2` gives true. The fullform are the same. Why there is a difference in caching. What is caching mechanism in the evaluation sequence? Is there any doc about this?

Comment: There wouldn't be docs about this, it's deep in the kernel code.  `ParulaCM` and `ParulaCM2` are `SameQ` because they have the exact same underlying structure.  But at the kernel level they are pointers to different addresses, different but possibly duplicate data structures.  If this caching were working properly, all you'd notice is that when you use a previously constructed `Blend` function, it doesn't have to make a new interpolation function every time, because it already made one and cached it.